# Prevent child theme from inheriting a parent theme's required file

Tags: child-theme

My parent theme has a file with a class that defines ads for that specific theme. It is required in functions.php.
My child theme needs a duplicate file with different ad parameters so I would like to not include the parent theme's file.

Is there an easy way to ensure the parent theme file will not be required in the child theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`is_child_theme()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_child_theme) in the parent theme's `functions.php` file:

```
if ( ! is_child_theme() ) {
    require( 'path/to/ads/file.php' );
}
```

**Update**

If you don't want to edit the parent theme -- for instance, so that any updates to the parent theme won't overwrite what you've done -- you could do something like this in the child theme's `functions.php` file:

```
global $ads_class; // whatever your ads class is named
if ( 
    is_child_theme() && 
    ( 
      class_exists( 'Ads_Class' ) && 
      'Ads_Class' == get_class( $ads_class) 
    )
   ) {
    $ads_class->__destruct();
}
```